# How can I create a range filter in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to create a query that extract objects that has on field startTime the year 2017 and then another one for year 2018.

This is the format for startTime :

```
"startTime": "2017-06-11T08:00:00",
```

The query I have written :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "startTime": {
              "gte": "2017",
              "lt": "2018"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Yes it return the object that has the startTime on year 2017 but if I do :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "startTime": {
              "gte": "2018",
              "lt": "2019"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It does return also objects  from 2017.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is the field `startTime` actually mapped to the date type?

Comment: yes I think so,,,

Comment: @Sirko I want to extract the objects that has as as startTime a date between 1st January 2017 and 31 st December 2017

Comment: Maybe try to provide the format of your input explicitly: `{ "gte": "2018", "lt": "2019", "format": "yyyy" }` or specify the full ISO compliant dates.

Comment: Yes!!! That was the answear: "format": "yyyy"  was missing and now it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure, that the field is actually of [type Date](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html).

If the problem persists, Elastic allows you to specify a [date-format for the query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#_date_format_in_range_queries). Adding a format of `yyyy` to your example, results in:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "startTime": {
              "gte": "2018",
              "lt": "2019",
              "format": "yyyy"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```